# Setting offer throughput or autopilot on container is not supported for serverless accounts. Azure Cosmos DB migration tool

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

After Selecting all the details correct in Migration tool returns the error related throughput value and having 0 or -1 does not help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I also bumped into this issue and couldn't solve it. I tried to copy between two serverless CosmosDb accounts, the container was existing on the target. If I omitted the value for throughput it just didn't proceed because of validation error. 
This rendered the tool unusable for me.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround to migrate data using tool is to just create the collection first in Azure portal Cosmos DB and then run the Migration tool with same details then it will add all the rows to the same collection created. Main issue here was creation of new collection but i do not know why it returns something related to throughput which i think does not have anything to do with it.

Comment: `Main issue here was creation of new collection but i do not know why it returns something related to throughput which i think does not have anything to do with it.` - This is because the migration tool tries to create a container with certain throughput which is not allowed for serverless accounts. By creating container beforehand, migration tool kind of skips the step of creating the container. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

In general, setting an explicitly value for `offer_throughput` is not allowed for serverless type of accounts. So either you omit that value and it will be applied by default one or you change your account type.

Related issues (still opened as of 23/02/2022):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/94814/cosmos-quick-start-gt-create-items-contaner-gt-htt.html
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/861

Answer (score 0):

In my **CosmosDBTrigger** configuration I set up as follows

```
     public async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(databaseName: "%CosmosDB:Database%", collectionName:  "%CosmosDB:VdrContainer%",
                                           ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDB:ConnectionString", LeaseCollectionName = "%CosmosDB:VdrContainerLease%",
                                           LeaseCollectionPrefix = "ubb-func-vdr-enrichment", CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true,
                                           FeedPollDelay = 10000, LeaseAcquireInterval = 5000, LeasesCollectionThroughput = 5000)]
                                           IReadOnlyList<Document> documents)
    {
     // Code goes here
    }
```

After I removed **LeasesCollectionThroughput**, the application started to work successfully.

along with that check DatabaseName, ContainerName, and ConnectionString